# Batch echo = without line break

Tags: batch-file, echo, newline, line-breaks

I want to echo the equal sign = without a line break.

I've tried these lines of code:

```
echo|set /p="="
    -> syntax error
echo|set /p="^="
    -> ^=
set temp=text
echo|set /p="%temp:text==%"
    -> syntax error
```

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: If for whatever reason you still need to be able to do this after considering the point @Mofi makes above, see [this solution](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4213#p23564)

Comment: The duplicate answer seems to be different, but in fact the same solutution works for equal signs, too

Comment: For just a single `=` character, I would do it as a single line command in my batch-file, `@For /F %%G In ('Prompt $H^&For %%H In (1^)Do Rem') Do @Set /P "=:%%G="`. For just a single space character, I'd use the same technique, `@For /F %%G In ('Prompt $H^&For %%H In (1^)Do Rem') Do @Set /P "=:%%G "`